# View appears behind backdrop/backround when UIActivityViewController is active

Tags: ios, swift, react-native-ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am looking to find out how in React Native or even just iOS Native with Swift the following is achieved.

WeCollect and Reading Queue have great examples of showing a tip to enable their share extension (See screenshots)
[image]
[image]

In my first effort at implementing this, the view is behind the backdrop / background when the action sheet is active. I am using `react-native-modal` to show the Tip above the Native action sheet
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the understanding you want to bring the view to from therefore
Do this in view did Load

```
view.bringSubview(toFront: theuielemntyouwanttobringtofront)
```